# am facing issue with getting the size of arraylist of arraylist

Tags: java, android

am trying to get the size of the arraylist, can anyone help me out.the code is added below.

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> gBtnId=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @mithun Show more code of what you are trying

Comment: [`gBtnId.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--) or ask a more detailed question.

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> gBtnId=new ArrayList<>();
        gBtnId.add(Singleton.getInstance().getButtonId());
        Log.v("tag",""+gBtnId);
        Log.v("tag1",""+gBtnId.size());
        if(gBtnId.size()!=1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you left somthing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: am trying to validadate.so if the size is less than 1 it should give false,the thing i used size() bt it gives size of that array bt i need to ge size of arrsylist within the arraylist.

Comment: If you have more code to add, [edit] your question. Don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an ArrayList in Java can be retrieved using the size() function. Some sample code will help illustrate this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int size_of_list = list.size();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `gBtnId.size();` which returns the size of ArrayList gBtnId which Contains a Collections of Integer Array Lists.

Example Program:

```
    ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();
         ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> gBtnId=new ArrayList<>();
        //add Elements
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("Add element :"+i);
        arrayList.add(i);
        }
System.out.println("Size of gBtnId Before Adding ArrayList---- "+gBtnId.size());
        gBtnId.addAll(arrayList);
System.out.println("Size of gBtnId AfterAdding ArrayList---- "+gBtnId.size());
```

Answer (score -1):

In that case there can be multiple arraylist within your outer arraylist, so out of that list whichever arraylist you want size of you can do like

```
parentArrayList.get(positionOfChildArrayList).size()
```